# How to hide a desktop app made using Microsoft visual c# from task manager and registry?

Tags: c#-4.0, registry, taskmanager

i am making a desktop security app using Microsoft visual c# .net version 4. I want my app to be hidden from registry and task manager when the exe runs. Is there any possible way to do it???

Comment: An application that cannot be seen by The User and thus not be terminated - IS - a security RISK. I guess this is not even possible for exactly that reason, but proove me wrong if it's not true. But it sould be possible to change the app's priority level in a manner that it can't be terminated by the User, e.g. have it running as a system application.

Comment: termination is not a problem for me.. it terminates automatically at a particular time.. i just want a way by which the app is hidden from the task manager and the registry.. the admin of the system may see it but should be hidden for others..